# Calendar app for Android with yearly event occurrence count

Tags: android, calendar

I'm looking for a calendar app for Android that displays the occurrence count for yearly repeating events.

For example if I create a (shared Google) calendar with an event named **Test** on 26th May 2010 recurring yearly, I would like this app to display **Test (#8)** on the 26th May 2018 (today). In this way I know that 8 years have passed.

There's [Pure Calendar Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.koxx.pure_calendar) that has an option to do this, but I need an **app** (not a widget) because I would like to go forward and back in time whenever needed.

Comment: Weird thought: create a contact named "Test" with a birth date of 26th May 2010. On 26th May 2018 (or before) you'd receive a notification reminding you of the 8th birthday.

Comment: @Izzy Of course it works, but the events that I need to be reminded are on a _shared Google calendar_ so I cannot copy all of them on fake contacts. The problem is that a feature like this is not documented on the Play Store descriptions, hence I'm asking here for help (if someone maybe is using an app that does it).